How to implement TreeList from ReactiveSearch with React Virtualization or lazy loading?
I'm working on a use case where I need to display a large dataset with a hierarchical structure (Make/Model/Component) in a tree-like filter component using ReactiveSearche's TreeList.
I've tried updating queries on the server side & nested aggregation or even React Virtualized, but I'm struggling with managing and rendering deeply nested data efficiently.
It is taking ~5 minutes to load ~130k overall values(ElasticSearch limit).
How can I make it load efficiently?
I tried the following things:**
Server Query Adjustments:** Attempted to mimic cloud-based query behaviors on a local server setup which did not yield improvements in performance or accuracy.
Implementation of Nested Aggregations: Employed to manage extensive datasets, but this approach has exacerbated performance issues and failed to efficiently manage data scale.
React Virtualized: Tried to integrate React Virtualized in the approach but could not implement a suitable technique that’s compatible with TreeList from ReactiveSearch since it is not supported natively.
